# Configuring Many-to-One relationship correctly ef core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi, automapper, .net-5

I am using the CQRS pattern in my project. I want it to be possible that my customer entity has an array of addresses, so I have configured a one-to-many EF relationship. However, when I create a new customer and then retrieve it, the addresses' field is just an empty array:

```json
{
   "id": 1,
   "firstName": "string",
   "lastName": "string",
   "phone": "string",
   "email": "string",
   "primaryContact": "string",
   "secondaryContact": "string",
   "addresses": [],
   "orders": []
}
```

I'm fairly new to using AutoMapper, so I am wondering if I am not configuring the relationship properly

Customer Entity:

```cs
public class Customer : AuditableEntity
{
   public string FirstName { get; set; }
   public string LastName { get; set; }
   public string Phone { get; set; }
   public string Email { get; set; }
   public string PrimaryContact { get; set; }
   public string SecondaryContact { get; set; }

   #region Navigation Properties

   public virtual ICollection<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
   public virtual ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; }

   #endregion
}
```

Address Entity:

```cs
public class Address : AuditableEntity
{
   public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }
   public string AddressLine2 { get; set; }
   public string Region { get; set; }
   public string PostalCode { get; set; }
   public string Country { get; set; }
}
```

The AddressDTO is just the properties set in the address entity, without the navigations properties.

```cs
public class AddressCreateDto
{
   public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }
   public string AddressLine2 { get; set; }
   public string Region { get; set; }
   public string PostalCode { get; set; }
   public string Country { get; set; }
}
```

GetCustomerByIdResponse

```cs
public class GetCustomerByIdResponse
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string FirstName { get; set; }
   public string LastName { get; set; }
   public string Phone { get; set; }
   public string Email { get; set; }
   public string PrimaryContact { get; set; }
   public string SecondaryContact { get; set; }
        
   public virtual ICollection<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
   public virtual ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}
```

My Auto Mapper profile:

```cs
public AddressProfile()
{
   CreateMap<AddressCreateDto, Address>().ReverseMap();
   CreateMap<CreateCustomerCommand, Address>().ReverseMap();
}

public CustomerProfile()
{
   CreateMap<CreateCustomerCommand, Customer>().ReverseMap();
   CreateMap<GetCustomerByIdResponse, Customer>()
      .ForMember(dst => dst.Orders, opt => opt.MapFrom(src =>
                 src.Orders))
      .ReverseMap();
}
```

Comment: You wrote that `Customer` should have array of `Address`es, but in your code the Custome has only one address and address has many customers.

Comment: Thanks. I have changed the customer entity to have a collection of addresses and removed the collection of customers from address. I removed the mappings for the addresses collection in customer because I received an exception:
```Error Mapping Types: 
CreateCustomerCommand -> Customer
Type Map configuration: CreateCustomerCommand -> Customer 
CreateCustomerCommand -> Customer
Destination Member: Addresses```.
However, the problem I have still persists.

Comment: http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Queryable-Extensions.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After fixing the relations from pre-edited post like you did, I would check and make sure that when retrieving `Customer` entity using EF you are using the

```
Include(x => x.Addresses)
```

So it will look somewhat like this (in simplified version)

```
var customers = Customers
    .Include(x => x.Addresses)
    .Include(x => x.Orders)
    .ToList();
```

Otherwise EF core will not grab them from db. Same goes for `Orders`, they need separate `Include` declaration.

Comment: this was a factor, but the main problem was me not assigning the collection value
```C#
var customer = _mapper.Map<Customer>(request);
var addressList = _mapper.Map<List<Address>>(request.Addresses);
customer.Addresses = addressList;
```